Closed form expression for series $f_\alpha(x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} (-n)^{\alpha} x^{2n}$
Let $\alpha \in \mathbb N$, and consider the Taylor series
$$f_\alpha(x) = \sum_{n >0} (-n)^{\alpha} x^{2n}$$
which  is convergent for $|x|<1$.

Question: can we find a closed form to express $f_\alpha(x)$?

I worked out two cases:
$$\alpha = 0 \Rightarrow f_\alpha(x) = \frac{x^2}{(1-x^2)}$$  and
if $$\alpha = 1 \Rightarrow f_\alpha(x) = \frac{-x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}$$
I don't see however how to get to the general $\alpha$.

Take the $(-1)^{\alpha}$ in front and change $x^2=z$ and then you get just $\sum n^{\alpha}z^n$ which is obtained inductively by applying $zd/dz$ to the geometric series

In your $\alpha=0$ case, do you take into account the $(-0)^0 x^{2\cdot 0}$ term?  Of course when $\alpha \ge 1$, the $n=0$ term is zero.

@GEdgar thanks!

We first note that $f_\alpha(x) = (-1)^\alpha \sum_{n\geq 0} n^\alpha (x^2)^\alpha$. So, it suffices to look at the function $\sum_{n\geq 0} n^\alpha y^\alpha$. This can be written in terms of the Polylogarithm:
$$f_\alpha(x) = (-1)^\alpha \mathrm{Li}_{-\alpha}(x^2).$$
See here for the first few special cases and some closed form formulae.
